# view html in array export

Tags: php, html, arrays, export

I have an array that contains html (table-structure).
If I do

```
$var = array('<table>', '<tr>', '<td>', 'content', '</td>', '</tr>', '</table>');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($var, 50);
echo '</pre>';
```

It outputs the content of the array but it creates a table.
I would like to export the html as well.

Current export:
`Array
(
    [0] => content
)`

What I would like:
`Array
(
    [0] => <table> <tr> <td> content </td> </tr> </table>
)`

Is this possible?

M.

Comment: What is your issue? Do you intend to use `print_r` in production, or you just want to see the output for debugging?

Comment: I just want to see the output for debugging

Comment: Use firebug to view html content or view source

Comment: As above, view source or inspect element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,It is working and shows excepted output
    $var = array('', '', '', 'content', '', '', '');

```
print_r(array(htmlentities(implode(" ", $var))));
```

Answer (score 1):

try

EDIT:

```
print_r(htmlspecialchars(implode(" ", $var)), 50);
```

Comment: I need them to stay an array because later on I merge it with another array, but thnx for the feedback

Comment: implode doesn't change the original array, so you should be able to keep the var array for later use

Comment: @Interactive the original array didn't change, there is no assignment so its still there, and whats up with the `50`?

Comment: @Tony Well output doesn't change so in a way you are right, but it still doesn't show the HTML. BTW the brackets cause an error for display. @Ghost The 50 is just for debugginh to make sure all the content is in `Array ( [0] )`

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I've got it working thnx to a answer in the comments

Comment: try the edit, if you want it in an array then syntax will depend on the php version.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
foreach( $var as $v )
    echo $v . " ";
```

var_dump is primarilly a function used for debugging, i.e. printing out objects to view internals.

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($var);
```

will output something similar to your result above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array('<table>', '<tr>', '<td>', 'content', '</td>', '</tr>', '</table>');
$string[0] = implode(" ",$var);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";
```